# cocossharp TilePropertiesForGID(info.Gid) always return null

Tags: xamarin, cocossharp

I am using the CocoSharp.PCL.Shared Nuget version 1.6.2 and I am trying to get the tile property.

**Here is the TileSet.tsx:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<tileset version="1.2" tiledversion="1.2.1" name="wood_tileset" tilewidth="32" tileheight="32" tilecount="256" columns="16">
 <image source="wood_tileset.png" width="512" height="512"/>
 <tile id="68">
  <properties>
   <property name="IsTreasure" value="true"/>
  </properties>
 </tile>
</tileset>
```

**The function I call to get my property:**

```
void HandleCustomTilePropertyAt(int worldX, int worldY, CCTileMapLayer layer)
    {
        CCTileMapCoordinates tileAtXy = layer.ClosestTileCoordAtNodePosition(new CCPoint(worldX, worldY));

        CCTileGidAndFlags info = layer.TileGIDAndFlags(tileAtXy.Column, tileAtXy.Row);

        if (info != null && info.Gid == 68)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> properties = null;

            try
            {
                properties = tileMap.TilePropertiesForGID(info.Gid);
            }
            catch
            {
                // CocosSharp 
            }

            if (properties != null && properties.ContainsKey("IsTreasure") && properties["IsTreasure"] == "true" )
            {
                layer.RemoveTile(tileAtXy);

                // todo: Create a treasure chest entity
            }
        }
    }
```

The problem is that : `properties = tileMap.TilePropertiesForGID(info.Gid);` always return null.

But if I break and look into the non-public variable, I can see the property of my tile : 
[image]

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I did not understand your question properly to be very honest can you be a bit clear please?

Comment: My problem is that "properties" is always null. But it should contains all the properties in the xml file. Is the Cocosharp library is broken ?

Comment: No its not it is working properly as per my knowledge

Comment: wich framework should I use to make a game in C# for a crossplatform development? I dont want to use unity.

Comment: Well I am not the right person to answer this, I am aware that in native iOS you use cocos 2D and 3D for game development, i am not sure whether or not xamarin has an equivalent

Comment: CocosSharp ,MonoGame and UrhoSharp are used for a crossplatform development  ,you could refer to this link. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/graphics-games/monogame/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to get my tile properties.

1. Get a stream from the tileset.tsx
2. Get the properties from a specifi tile id
3. Create a function that parse the xml file tileset.tsx to make it works as cocossharp used to work.

In **Program.cs**, Since it inherit from activity, I am able to open all assets :

```
public class Program : AndroidGameActivity
{

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        CCApplication application = new CCApplication();
        application.ApplicationDelegate = new AppDelegate();

        this.SetContentView(application.AndroidContentView);
        this.LoadTileMapProperty();

        application.StartGame();
    }

    private void LoadTileMapProperty()
    {
        Settings.TileMapStream = new StreamReader(Assets.Open("Content/tileMap/wood_tileset.tsx"));
    }

}
```

in my **GameLayer.cs** :

```
 void HandleCustomTilePropertyAt(int worldX, int worldY, CCTileMapLayer layer)
    {
        CCTileMapCoordinates tileAtXy = layer.ClosestTileCoordAtNodePosition(new CCPoint(worldX, worldY));

        CCTileGidAndFlags info = layer.TileGIDAndFlags(tileAtXy.Column, tileAtXy.Row);

        if (info != null && info.Gid == 68)
        {
            Dictionary<string, string> properties = null;

            try
            {
                properties = tileMap.TilePropertiesForTileID(info.Gid);
            }
            catch
            {
                // CocosSharp 
            }

            if (properties != null && properties.ContainsKey("IsTreasure") && properties["IsTreasure"] == "true")
            {
                //test adding entity via tileMap
                reliefLayer.AddChild(new Tree(tileAtXy), 3);
            }
        }
    }
```

Then I replaced the function given by Cocossharp library by this function :

```
public Dictionary<string, string> TilePropertiesForTileID(short tileGid)
    {
        Dictionary<string, string> propertiesDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        try
        {
            // Loading from a file, you can also load from a stream
            var xmlDoc = XDocument.Load(Settings.TileMapStream);

            // Query the data and write out a subset of contacts
            var propertiesQuery = xmlDoc.Root.Descendants("tile")
                                        .Where(item => (int)item.Attribute("id") == tileGid)
                                        .SelectMany(a => a.Descendants("property"))
                                        .Select(property => new
                                        {
                                            Name = property.Attribute("name").Value,
                                            Value = property.Attribute("value").Value
                                        })
                                        .ToList();

            foreach (var property in propertiesQuery)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Property Name: {property.Name}, Value: {property.Value}");
                propertiesDict.Add(property.Name, property.Value);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex);
        }


        return propertiesDict;
    }
```